# Deselect creation of start menu and desktop icons in "Portable mode" in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following under `[Tasks]`

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Create a Desktop shortcut";
Name: "startmenu"; Description: "Create a Start Menu entry";
Name: "portablemode"; Description: "Portable Mode"; Flags: unchecked
```

and under `[Setup]`

```
Uninstallable=not WizardIsTaskSelected('portablemode')
```

I'd like the `desktopicon` and `startmenu` tasks to be deselected when a user selects `portablemode`, since these options are useless under the `portablemode` installation configuration:

[image]

If there is a cleaner way to do this I am also interested in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about having two [setup types](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection) – *"Full installation"* and *"Portable mode"*? And allowing the icons tasks for the *"Full installation"* type only?

For `Uninstallable`, use [`WizardIsComponentSelected`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected).

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=WizardIsComponentSelected('full')

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "portable"; Description: "Portable mode"

[Components]
Name: "full"; Description: "full"; Types: full

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Create a Desktop shortcut"; Components: full
Name: "startmenu"; Description: "Create a Start Menu entry"; Components: full
```

[image]